# Angular with AWS-amplify API and Auth unexpected behavior leads to 403 unauthorized

Tags: angular, session, authentication, amazon-iam, aws-amplify

I have angular project that has AWS-Amplify configured for using API and AUTH, I have successfully called my AWS-IAM secured Serverless API using amplify and it returns the expected result.

For some reason sometimes it does not and throws 403 error, I have noticed this behavior after signing out then signing in again, after that if I called the api it will return 403, but if I signed in and refreshed the page then it will make a successful call.

Im new to web development, sessions, and authentications, but I think that my session should be saved somewhere so it can be always retrieved? am I right about this? any suggestions please mainly with AWS services?

```
  isLoggedIn(message: string, isLoggedIn: boolean) {
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      this.router.navigate(['/securehome']);
      this.test();
    }
  }

  async test() {
    try {
      const notes = await this.orders();
      alert(notes);
    } catch (e) {
      alert("why? " + e);
    }
  }

  orders() {
    return API.get("orders", "/orders", '');
  }
```

Comment: There must be a success callback also. Try to get response in that method because it is async request

Comment: @MukulSharma I have edited my code and now its working but not as expected, sometimes it returns 403 every now and then, I think this why I need a success callback?

Comment: Yes..A callback is must for asynch response. Even after after edition it doesn't seem me a proper callback over there.

Comment: @mukulsharma I don't really understand callbacks! and where should I add that?

Comment: -- sometimes it returns 403 every now and then,  -- Were you able to find any reason or solutions for this?

Comment: @Aman Gupta you can save the session in the local storage